# jQuery star rating plugin that clears rating on rated star click?

Tags: jquery, rating

This is baffling, but I can't seem to find a decent jQuery star rating plugin that clears the rating when you click on a rated star (as in: you rate 3 stars, you click the 3rd star again, and the rating is removed). I keep finding plugins that have that silly "clear rating" button to the left of the stars.
When I was using prototype I was using ratingbox, which worked well, but I can't find a jQuery equivalent.

I would greatly appreciate any recommendations!

Comment: The easiest thing might be to find one that fits your needs as closely as possible and then modify it.

Comment: I think that might be the way to go. I was hoping that someone out there had done it better than I would, but I'm not finding it. Time to get my hands dirty!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need any special functionality, you can use my code. Should be easy to convert it into a plugin if required.

If you don't need the hover tracking effect, just remove the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

The set rating is saved in a data attribute on the container div, you can access it via `$('.rating').data('rating')`.

Check out a live demo with some random images from the internet: http://jsfiddle.net/abPFF/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="rating" data-rating="3">
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.rating { display:inline-block; padding:0px; }
.rating div { display:inline-block; width:48px; height:48px; margin:0px; background-image: url('star-off.png');}

.selected { background-image: url('star.png') !important; }
.highlighted { background-image: url('star.png') !important; }
```

Javascript:

```
function ShowRating($element, rating){
    $stars = $element.find('div');
    $stars.removeClass('selected highlighted');
    rating = parseInt(rating);
    if(rating < 1 || rating > $stars.length) return;

    $stars.eq(rating-1).addClass('selected')
        .prevAll().addClass('highlighted');
    return;
}

$('.rating').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    ShowRating($this, $this.data('rating'));
}).bind({
    mouseleave: function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        ShowRating($this, $this.data('rating'));
    }
}).find('div').bind({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        ShowRating($this.parent(), $this.index() + 1);
    },
    click: function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $parent = $this.parent();
        var idx = $this.index() + 1;
        if($parent.data('rating') == idx){
            // Remove rating
            ShowRating($parent, 0);
            $parent.data('rating', 0);
        } else {
            // Set rating
            ShowRating($parent, idx);
            $parent.data('rating', idx);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Wow, you're coming through for me! Thanks!